# how i fix this error Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I installed babel plugin tansform runtime and add this on .babelrc

```
...
    "plugins": [ "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime" ]
```

i cleared my cache and new installed the whole npm modules but the error message still exists. Why?

Comment: may be file name is mispelled? it should be `.bebelrc` and not `.babelrtc`

Comment: its not the filename, i wrote the babel word only here wrong

Comment: add your package.json here